# How do I aggregate data from the morgan logging library?

Tags: node.js, performance, loggly

I have been using the Morgan logger on my node.js API to get some insights into how routes are performing with sample output such as:

2016-05-17T22:47:59.232Z - performance: GET /login 200 14.767 ms - 1157

I'm looking for a way to aggregate this type of data over a time period - but I'm at a loss as to how to do so. I had signed up for loggly as we had something similar set up in it at a previous company (splunk) - but for the life of me I can't see how I could achieve the output I want with that tool.

What can I do to capture, clean and then perform calculations on this type of data in a near real-time fashion?

The type of questions I'm looking to answer are:

- How do routes on an overall average perform month over month?
- What are my slowest routes over the last hour/day/week?
- What is the min/max/average of each route that gets accessed?
- How many requests do I get during a specific hour of the day?

Any help is appreciated, this is new territory for me and google isn't coming up with much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use an APM suite such as NewRelic or AppDynamics.